# Connecting OnPrem REST API to Azure API Management using Azure Service Bus Relay

Tags: azure, azure-servicebusrelay

Is it possible to publish/import OnPrem REST API to Azure API Management using Azure Service Bus relay?
If so, please let me know with some example case , if possible...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you reference [import an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-get-started#a-namecreate-api-aimport-an-api)? We could import API to API management with WADL or Swagger format from clipboard, file or URL.

Comment: In my case using "Azure API Management-->Relay-->OnPrem Service", I dont get any WADL Or Swagger. I just get relay endpoint....So, it is not possible to use  "import method".

Comment: `Connecting OnPrem REST API to Azure API Management using Azure Service Bus Relay`. It seems that it could be done. I found a [tutorials](http://microsoftintegration.guru/2015/02/05/azure-api-management-azure-service-bus-minecraft/) mentioned this,hope it is useful.